# ExpressJs wait for task or timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple app which convert speech to text, but sometime the API may timeout depending on the length of video. How can I use the promise race (or any other approach) to see which function resolve first to return the `jobid` in case of timeout, or the task result in case of task completed successfully before timing out.

Here is my attempt, but the app doesn't wait for promise race.

```
const taskRunner = async (data) => {
    // run the task and return the result
    return 'Hello world!';
};

const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve('timeout'), ms));

router.post('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    try {

        var data = { jobid: 1 };
        var task = new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
            const result = await taskRunner({ data });
            resolve(result);
        });

        Promise.race([task, timeout(10000)]).then(function (value) {
            console.log(value);
            if(value === 'timeout'){
                data.status = "pending";
                data.tracker = `/job/${data.jobid}`
            }else{
                data.status = "completed";
                data.text = value;
            }          
        });

        res.json(data);

    } catch (error) {
        error.statusCode = 400;
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with `await Promise.race` ?

Comment: Does the `taskRunner()` work properly?  Does it return a promise that resolves with its value?  If not, we need to see its code.

Comment: Put the `res.json(data)` inside the `.then()` handler.

Comment: thanks, using await Promise.race() with .then() solved it.